Fluid calculation in OpenModelica
I am trying to build my library for hydraulic calculations. I have a problem with the pipe model.
This is what my pipe model looks like:
model pipe_v0

import Modelica.Units.SI;

  parameter SI.Area muF = 8e-5;
  parameter SI.Density rho = 998;
  parameter SI.SpecificHeatCapacityAtConstantPressure cp = 4200;
  SI.Pressure dp;
  parameter Real dt = 10;

SI.MassFlowRate G;
SI.Pressure pin, pout;
SI.Temperature tin, tout;

  Port.port_b port_b annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-100, 0}, extent = {{-5, -5}, {5, 5}}), iconTransformation(origin = {-100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Port.port_a port_a annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {100, 0}, extent = {{-5, -5}, {5, 5}}), iconTransformation(origin = {100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
equation
G = muF*sqrt(2*rho*dp);
 
  pout = pin - dp;
  tout = tin + dt;
  
  port_b.p = pin;
  port_a.p = pout;

  port_b.h = tin*cp;
  port_a.h = tout*cp;

port_b.m = G;
port_a.m = -G;

port_b.H + port_a.H = 0;

annotation(
    Icon(graphics = {Rectangle( lineColor = {144, 144, 144}, fillColor = {190, 190, 190}, fillPattern = FillPattern.HorizontalCylinder, extent = {{-100, 10}, {100, -10}})}));
end pipe_v0;

And these are models of my boundary conditions:
model bound_PT
extends Librero.Sourse.bound_base;
import Modelica.Units.SI;

parameter SI.Pressure p;
parameter SI.Temperature T;
SI.SpecificHeatCapacityAtConstantPressure cp = 4200;

equation
port_a.p = p;
T = port_a.h/cp;

annotation(
    Diagram,
    Icon(graphics = {Text(origin = {13, -61}, rotation = 30, extent = {{-100, 20}, {100, -20}}, textString = "%name", fontName = "GOST Common")}));
end bound_PT;

and another one:
model bound_mH
extends Librero.Sourse.bound_base;
import Modelica.Units.SI;

parameter SI.MassFlowRate m;
parameter SI.EnthalpyFlowRate H;


equation
port_a.m = m;
port_a.H = H;

annotation(
    Diagram,
    Icon(graphics = {Text(origin = {45, -49}, rotation = 33, extent = {{-100, 20}, {100, -20}}, textString = "%name", fontName = "GOST Common")}));
end bound_mH;

When I try to calculate one pipe (One pipe model is closed by two boundary conditions) everything works out.
If I want to merge the flow so that depending on the hydraulic characteristics, the mass flow is divided, then the calculation gives the following error:
[1] 18:07:22 Symbolic Error An independent subset of the model has imbalanced number of equations (18) and variables (17). variables:
Although when I check the model (see image) it tells me that everything is fine:
[1] 18:07:21 Scripting Notification Check of Librero.poligon.st completed successfully. Class Librero.poligon.st has 56 equation(s) and 56 variable(s). 37 of these are trivial equation(s).
image of problem model
What's wrong? Thanks for help :-)
Update #1
Here is the connector code:
connector port_base
  import Modelica.Units.SI;
    SI.Pressure p;
    SI.SpecificEnthalpy h;
    flow SI.MassFlowRate m;
    flow SI.EnthalpyFlowRate H;
end port_base;

For the connector model, I simply apply extends Librero.Port.port_base; and drew an icon

Could you provide the code for the connectors as well?

@Clement44
Of course. I added the connector code to the question in the update

I tried removing all h and H related equations, and the model works (with 2 pressure inputs and 1 mass flowrate output). So that would indicate that the issue has something to do with the thermal part of your modelling. Somehow, I don't see how I could solve for H upstream the mixing point with the current modelling.
Upon further reflection, I can't fathom why you would define two flow variables, since port.H will be directly linked to port.m and port.h. Wouldn't something based on Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort be more practical?
  connector FluidPort

  flow Medium.MassFlowRate m_flow "Mass flow rate from the connection point into the component";
  Medium.AbsolutePressure p "Thermodynamic pressure in the connection point";
  stream Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h_outflow "Specific thermodynamic enthalpy close to the connection point if m_flow < 0";

  end FluidPort;


I am defining two flow variables because I need to transfer pressure p and temperature T (which is expressed through enthalpy h and heat capacity cp). Since these are two potential variables, I need two flow variables. For this purpose, I use mass flow rate m and enthalpy flow rate H.

The standard library Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort does not suit me because I want to write a library in which I understand all the processes on 100%. I am doing this to simplify what I was solving manualy in Wolfram Mathematica and also to learn OpenModelica, as I am a beginner in this field. At this stage, it will be needed to solve a static system of equations.

Somehow, I don't see how I could solve for H upstream of the mixing point with the current modeling.
I agree with you, and now I am trying to address this issue. I discovered that in Modelica.Media.Examples.Utilities there are models similar to what I am doing, so I hope I can achieve my goal. I would appreciate any advice, and when I succeed, I will report on it.

That's why the stream prefix has been added in the Modelica Language Specification. Have a look into it: you will end up with a better coded library :)
